# Fitting volatility using SABR

Tags: option-pricing, interest-rates, implied-volatility, volatility-surface, sabr

I have been working on generating a volatility surface for options on SOFR futures with the help of the SABR model. I am running into some trouble for low strikes in particular, in that I cannot seem to find an adequate fit (will explain more what I mean by adequate later).

My process is essentially the below:

- Solve for implied black (I also solve for bachelier) vols for out of the money options across the selection of strikes I am interested in (only taking into account the first unique price listed)
- Calibrate SABR using the provided implementation in QuantLib (this gives a good fit for my purposes but not great)
- Modify parameters to attempt to fit the smile in the places I care most about
- Once I have a fit for each expiry I feed the vols into QuantLib's BlackVarianceSurface implementation to interpolate over tenor
- Note if I use the black variation I end up in normal anyway via Hagan's transform since the market is quoted in normal vols

The surface does very well for high strikes and somewhat well for ATM, however for low strikes (\$97-\$100+, 3%-0%) I am too high. When I say too high, I am specifically attempting to fit my surface to exchange settles so that when pricing caps/floors I get a good match for a cap price vs. a call strip of same tenor on the exchange. That is the idea at least.

The pictures below should explain more:

Initial calibration for single expiry (normal)
[image: Initial calibration for single expiry (normal)]

As you can see it misses the ATM (the yellow dot), now I can fix this, however I am way too high on the low strikes, as seen below:

[image]

Note that this essentially uses the normal variation of SABR (beta = 0), however the behavior doesn't seem to change when employing the lognormal variation as seen below:

Initial calibration (Black, lognormal variation, Beta = 1):
[image]

Adjusted:
[image: Adjusted]

I am expecting the behavior to be more similar to the below images when using the lognormal variation, i.e. producing lower vols on the ends.

[image]

I am at a loss for why this is not occurring. I don't believe it has to do with my code, and think it is likely to do with me having misunderstood some aspect of the SABR model. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible info here: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2529684

Comment: Appreciate the link, though after reading the abstract I don't believe it directly relates to the current issue I am having.

Comment: There is no way SABR will be able to match this shape. It's only a few parameters after all.

Comment: I’ve done a lot of research in the last month or so and understand this now. I am still curious why I might not be getting the behavior at the ends identified in the above post with the final photos when beta is set to 1. The rest I understand much better and I am able to generate a very good surface for caps and floors with this.